# Is there any way to fix the zoom buttons to the map?

Tags: css, openlayers

We have zoom buttons inside a map and I can't manage to fix'em -> When I resize the window, those buttons are not following the right way while the layer switcher button is doing well.

I already tried providing the right css but none of I tried seems to work, and I've done a lot of things with css.

In fact, when I reduce the window size, the buttons are moving the right way, but not enough and consequently they are finally hidden.

Comment: Where are you trying to position the controls, which version of OpenLayers are you using, and what css are you attempting to use?  The OpenLayers default css should keep the controls in their default positions regardless of window size.

Answer (score -2):

**Try this**

```
scrollwheel: false,
```

This option is used for disable zoom on mouse.

```
scaleControl: false,
```

This option is used for disable zoom by scale.

```
draggable: false,
```

This option is used for disabling drag.

```
mapTypeControl: false,
```

This option will hide map type.

Put them as following:

```
var myOptions = {
   center: myLatlng,
   zoom: 15,
   mapTypeControl: false,
   draggable: false,
   scaleControl: false,
   scrollwheel: false,
   navigationControl: false,
   streetViewControl: false,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls

Comment: Not sure about this answer since the question is tagged with `openlayers`.

Comment: customizing google map you can follow above attached link

Comment: Sorry for not answering I resolved my problem just by letting the buttons at their initial place...